# вставить суммирующий столбец в DataFrame Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate

Голову сломал, как вставить в имеющийся DataFrame новый столбец, полученный суммированием значений слайса столбцов DataFrame?

Допустим, есть DataFrame:

```
type 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12
t1   1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
t2   2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
t3   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12
```

Хочу получить:

```
type 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 total
t1   1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  12 
t2   2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  24
t3   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 78
```

Допустим, `df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 3), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])`.

Пока придумал только: `df['total'] = df.transpose().sum().transpose()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

воспользуйтесь методом `.sum(axis=1)`

```
In [9]: df["total"] = df.iloc[:, 1:].sum(axis=1)
```

результат:

```
In [10]: df
Out[10]:
  type  01  02  03  04  ...  09  10  11  12  total
0   t1   1   1   1   1  ...   1   1   1   1     12
1   t2   2   2   2   2  ...   2   2   2   2     24
2   t3   1   2   3   4  ...   9  10  11  12     78

[3 rows x 14 columns]
```